# How to get the same specific colors from the original image to new created image with the same amount of color and same width and height?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the original image, colorslevels1.jpg:

[image: colors levels]

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HG6M.jpg)

Then I'm using this both methods to get specific colors from the image and put the colors in a new image.

```
private List<Color> GetColors()
{
    if (bmp != null)
    {
        List<string> targetColors = new List<string>
{
    "#ff00fe",
    "#d00078",
    "#e10a12",
    "#fb3f00",
    "#ff7d01",
    "#ffa800",
    "#ffcf00",
    "#fefd19",
    "#7cff21",
    "#12f218",
    "#01d31c",
    "#00b02c",
    "#008c4d",
    "#00a09b",
    "#00c3c9",
    "#0165ef"
};

        bmp = new Bitmap(@"d:\Ffmpeg Capture\colorslevels1.jpg");

        int width = bmp.Width;
        int height = bmp.Height;

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
                string hexColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c).ToLower(); // Convert to lowercase

                // Check if the lowercase hex color matches any of the target colors
                if (targetColors.Contains(hexColor))
                {
                    colors.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }

        bmp.Dispose();

        // Save the bitmap with the colors once all colors are collected
        SaveColorsAsBitmap(colors, @"d:\test.bmp");
    }

    return colors;
}
```

this method save the hex colors as bitmap to the hard disk.

```
private void SaveColorsAsBitmap(List<Color> colors, string filePath)
{
    // Determine the dimensions of the bitmap
    int width = 200; // Set the desired width (adjust as needed)
    int height = colors.Count; // Set the height to the number of colors

    // Create a new transparent bitmap with the determined dimensions
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        // Clear the background to transparent
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        // Draw each color as a vertical line on the bitmap
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[i]))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(brush, 0, i, width, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Save the bitmap as a PNG file (PNG supports transparency)
    bitmap.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);

    // Dispose of the bitmap to release resources
    bitmap.Dispose();
}
```

in the method SaveColorsAsBitmap I set the width value to 200 because then it will be too small to see the colors in the new bitmap image. in the original the width value was 1.

the result is:

[image: result]

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbuIG.png)

in the result the new image has the colors I wanted but the width/height and number of colors for each color is not like in the original image.  this is the order and the colors that I want to get from the original image but the size(width/height) of each color is not like in the original.

how can I fix it to get the colors like in the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

1. If you look at the contents of the "colors" array after analyzing the source image and before calling SaveColorsAsBitmap, then there are too many values and they are repeated. I believe that the number of elements in the array should match the number of colors in the original image. First, before adding a color to the "colors" array, you need to check whether such a color already exists in the array or not. To do this, you can slightly change the structure of the "colors" array, namely, create a class that will contain the color value and its HEX representation. After this, the array will contain the number of colors that are in the original image.
2. In the SaveColorsAsBitmap method, you need to set the size of the rectangle that will be filled with color - widthColorBlock and heightColorBlock. Also, when drawing in Graphics, you must observe the step along the Y axis, that is, each subsequent color must be lower than the other.

[image: Result image]

P.S. Don't forget to change the path to the source and the resulting image in the code

Full code:

```
public class ColorItem
{
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public string hexColor { get; set; }
}

private List<ColorItem> GetColors()
{
    List<string> targetColors = new List<string>
    {
        "#ff00fe",
        "#d00078",
        "#e10a12",
        "#fb3f00",
        "#ff7d01",
        "#ffa800",
        "#ffcf00",
        "#fefd19",
        "#7cff21",
        "#12f218",
        "#01d31c",
        "#00b02c",
        "#008c4d",
        "#00a09b",
        "#00c3c9",
        "#0165ef"
    };

    List<ColorItem> colors = new List<ColorItem>();

    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(@"sourceImage.jpg"))
    {
        int width = bmp.Width;
        int height = bmp.Height;

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(i, j);
                string hexColor = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c).ToLower(); // Convert to lowercase

                // Check if the lowercase hex color matches any of the target colors
                if (targetColors.Contains(hexColor))
                {
                    if (colors.Count(d => d.hexColor == hexColor) == 0)
                    {
                        colors.Add(new ColorItem() { color = c, hexColor = hexColor });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the bitmap with the colors once all colors are collected
        SaveColorsAsBitmap(colors, @"resultImage.png");
    }

    return colors;
}

private void SaveColorsAsBitmap(List<ColorItem> colors, string filePath)
{
    int widthColorBlock = 39; // color rectangle width
    int heightColorBlock = 18; // color rectangle height

    int imageHeight = 377; //result image height
    int imageWidth = 106;  //result image width

    var startDrawColorsPoint = new Point(45, 38); // start point (x,y) for drawing colors

    var hexBackground = "#CECECE"; 
    var backgroundColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexBackground); // result image background color and hex color value

    var borderThickness = 1;  // thickness of lines around color (pixel)

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.Clear(backgroundColor);

            for (int i = 0; i < colors.Count; i++)
            {
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[i].color))
                {
                    //draw black border
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, startDrawColorsPoint.X, (heightColorBlock * i) + startDrawColorsPoint.Y, widthColorBlock, heightColorBlock + borderThickness);

                    //draw color block
                    var colorBlockPositionX = startDrawColorsPoint.X + borderThickness;
                    var colorBlockPositionY = startDrawColorsPoint.Y + (heightColorBlock * i) + borderThickness;
                    var colorBlockWidth = widthColorBlock - (borderThickness * 2);
                    var colorBlockHeight = heightColorBlock - borderThickness;

                    g.FillRectangle(brush, colorBlockPositionX, colorBlockPositionY, colorBlockWidth, colorBlockHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the bitmap as a PNG file (PNG supports transparency)
        bitmap.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error on new ColorItem() { color = c, hexColor = hexColor } Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Colors_Scanner.Form1.ColorItem' to 'string' Colors Scanner D:\Csharp Projects\Colors Scanner\Form1.cs 114 Active

Comment: @SharonLeni I made a typo, I updated the answer, please check

Comment: working.  just last knowledge question.  the original image size is width 106 and height 377 but if i set this in the method SaveColorsAsBitmap the widthLine to 106 and the heightLine to 377 is does not looking even close to the original image colors.  what is the reason ?  the original image also horizontal and vertical resolutions 96 dpi and bit depth 24.  is there a way to make the colors to be the same size like in the original image ?  without settings manual the widthLine and heightLine.

Comment: @SharonLeni take a look at the changes I made to the code. I've added variables to further customize result image. hope this helps you in your task.

Comment: how to draw the new image without any background color ?  I tried this:  g.Clear(Color.Transparent); but this leave white background.

Comment: @SharonLeni if I replace g.Clear(backgroundColor) with g.Clear(Color.Transparent) then the image is created with a transparent background. opening the image, for example, in Paint, you can see that the background is transparent. an important point is that the final file should be in PNG format when saving. but in the code presented above, there is already a PNG format. So I do not know what your problem is.